# Proving a set is an integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

The question asks to prove the set $R$ is an integral domain, where $R$ is defined as $\{\frac{a}{b}: a,b\in\Bbb Z, b\in 2\Bbb Z+1\}$.

I know that a set is an integral domain when there exists no zero devisors in that set. I also know that a zero devisor exists when there exists two non-zero elements in a set that when multiplied together equal $0$. Is its okay when answering this question to say that it is simply impossible for $a/b$ to equal $0$ unless the integer $a$ is equal to $0$, and therefore no zero devisors exist?

Thank you.

Comment: It is a subring of $\mathbb Q$, so...

Comment: It matters how addition and multiplication are defined on the *set* $R$.  If the operations are inherited from $\mathbb Q$, that should be stated for your Readers in the body of the Question.  The issue would then be to discover whether $R$ is closed with respect to those operations (and with respect to additive inverses).